# Obtaining GPS coordinates using internal GPS receiver and VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, gps

We currently have HP XP2 tablets with a built in internal GPS receiver.  What we'd like to achieve is obtain GPS Lat/Long coordinates using an MS Access database and VBA code.

Would it be possible for anyone to please provide the VBA code required to access the coordinates to make them available to add to our Access database?

Please see details below regarding GPS receiver model and drivers:
Driver = u-blox GNSS Location Sensor Driver. 
Description = The u-blox GNSS Location Sensor driver is required to enable the u-blox USB GPS standalone device. 
Standalone GPS name = HP Graff GNSS Module

Comment: Do you have any information about the GPS receiver or the drivers? Unfortunately, your question at the moment is very broad and without further research/information edited into it, could be a candidate for being closed.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly you want to extract with VBA the GPS coordinates from your internal GPS receiver and add them to a an Access database.

If that is the case, then unfortunately VBA is a language only used by MS office application, therefore if your built in GSP receiver is not an office application i'm quite sure you wont be able to extract the data using VBA (it is possible in a few cases but it requires a very advance knowledge of VBA) 
The easiest way for you would be to extract manually the data and save them in a specific location of your files and then ask the VBA macro to open the file and save the data in your database.
If you really want to extract the data without any human interaction, I suggest you use python or another programming language or check on the IFTTT website if you  can create an applet.

I hope this answer will help you!

If you need a more detailed question, you'll need to send more specification about your data, the built in GPS app...

Comment: If the GPS receiver software/drivers have APIs, then these can be referenced/integrated with Access VBA. So the VBA code will be written in the MS Access App and that will access the underlying components or data. Unfortunately, I don't have the experience here to provide an example.